# How to change '_class' of Web2py autocomplete widget

Tags: web2py

I loop through a form object to change all the classes:

```
form = crud.create(db.messages, next = URL('index'))
parts = ['title', 'body', 'subject'] # corresponding fields
classes = 'form-control col-md-12' # my classes
for p in parts:
    form.custom.widget[p]['_class'] = '%s %s' % (classes, form.custom.widget[p]['_type'])
```

This is working - but: `subject` is an autocomplete widget:

```
db.messages.subject.widget = SQLFORM.widgets.autocomplete(...)
```

and here `_class` is not changed (or altered afterwards again?)

How can this be fixed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autocomplete widget is a `TAG` object that contains two components, the first of which is the `INPUT` element. So, do something like:

```
if p == 'subject':
    form.custom.widget[p][0].add_class(classes)
```

Note, you can use the `add_class` method to add classes to an element that has an existing class.

Also, instead of manually changing all the classes, you might see if setting `crud.settings.formstyle` to "bootstrap3_stacked" or "bootstrap3_inline" works for you. If not, you can also write a custom formstyle function to generate the exact form layout you want.

Comment: Thanks for the various ways to solving this problem. I guess at a certain point one must try to read and understand the source code...

Comment: I use 'crud.settings' now - but one more question on it: Is it possible to switch to the bootstrap form validation states - instead of using the web2py default error visualization?

Comment: Sure, see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Hide-errors.