# web2py autocomplete widget not "CSS-friendly"?

Tags: autocomplete, web2py

In model:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
                 Field('auto'),
                 Field('manual')
                )
db.mytable.auto.widget=SQLFORM.widgets.autocomplete(request,db.mytable.auto)
```

In controller:

```
def index():
    form = SQLFORM(db.mytable)
    return locals()
```

Result: The field with autocomplete looks shitty like it doesn't get any CSS-styling, while the other field looks nice.

As descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570755/how-to-change-class-of-web2py-autocomplete-widget) I can do in the controller:

```
form.custom.widget['auto'][0].add_class('form-control')
```

Which makes the autocompleted field look nice, too.

But shouldn't it be normal behaviour for the autocomplete widget to provide the same CSS-friendly tags as other input fields?
Or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap 3 `formstyle` function (which is the default `formstyle` in the web2py scaffolding application) does not properly style the autocomplete widget (this should be corrected).

As a workaround, if you want the styling to affect all forms generated from the DAL model, you can also do this:

```
autocomplete = SQLFORM.widgets.autocomplete
db.mytable.auto.widget = \
    lambda f, v: autocomplete(request, db.mytable.auto)(f, v, _class='form-control')
```

Or to make a specialized Bootstrap autocomplete widget for use with any field, you can do:

```
def bootstrap_autocomplete(*args, **kwargs):
    widget = SQLFORM.widgets.autocomplete(*args, **kwargs)
    return lambda f, v: widget(f, v, _class='form-control')
```

Then when defining a model, you can do:

```
db.mytable.auto.widget = bootstrap_autocomplete(request, db.mytable.auto)
```

**UPDATE:** The autocomplete widget has been fixed -- it now uses the styling specified by `formstyle`, as with other form widgets. So, the above workaround should no longer be needed.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. Your suggestion works with directly generated forms but not with create or edit forms generated from a grid or smartgrid. In that case very strange things happen: instead of a suggestion list, the parent-grid gets displayed, once you type into the autocomplete field.

Comment: First, I cannot reproduce the issue with smartgrid, so I suggest opening a new question and showing your code. Second, the problem you report would not be related to the above solution, which is only intended to answer your question about adding a CSS class to the autocomplete input element.

Comment: Thanks again. Your solution breaks if I do `form=SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.mytable)` instead of `form=SQLFORM(db.mytable)` so no need to post a new question. Anyways, my question was rather aimed at the general behaviour of the autocomplete widget: IMHO it should provide the same styling classes as all other generated forms so there would be no need to manually add a CSS class. I was hoping for some web2py core developers to comment on that..

Comment: First, I have tried the above with `smartgrid`, and as already noted, I cannot reproduce the problem you described, so you will need to post a new question with code if you would like to resolve that issue. Second, if you were simply looking for a comment from a core developer regarding a possible bug/potential enhancement, Stack Overflow is not the appropriate forum. Instead, you should start a discussion on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py) or post an issue on [Github](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues).