# web2py autocomplete widget not using bootstrap3 style

Tags: css, web2py

I tried to use the autocomplete widget as suggested by Anthony at [web2py autocomplete widget not "CSS-friendly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746656/web2py-autocomplete-widget-not-css-friendly), but could not succeed. 
My models:

```
db.define_table('bank',
            Field('category', 'string', default='BANK'),  
            Field('full_name', 'string', required=True, label='Name'),
            format='%(full_name)s'
            )

db.define_table('dd_master',
            Field('bank', 'reference bank', required=True),
            Field('bank_branch', 'reference bank_branch', required=True),

#db.dd_master.bank.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'bank.id', '%(full_name)s', orderby=db.bank.full_name, zero='Select')
```

Tried autocomplete widget. bootstrap syling not working.

```
db.dd_master.bank.widget = SQLFORM.widgets.autocomplete(request, db.bank.full_name, id_field=db.bank.id)
```

Tried workaround suggested by Anthony. Not working when autocomplete has 3 arguments.

```
autocomplete = SQLFORM.widgets.autocomplete
db.dd_master.bank.widget = lambda f, v: autocomplete(request, db.bank.full_name, id_field=db.bank.id)(f, v, _class='form-control')
```

Style comes correctly when it has two arguments, but when value entered in field, an image of the entire screen is pasted over

```
db.dd_master.bank.widget = lambda f, v: autocomplete(request, db.bank.full_name)(f, v, _class='form-control')
```

My controller:

```
def manage_dd():
    grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.dd_master, csv=False, details=False, deletable=False)
    return dict(grid=grid)
```

I could not understand where I am going wrong. How do I use Anthony's workaround correctly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce either issue using the latest web2py. Anyway, the workaround you reference should no longer be needed, as the autocomplete widget has been fixed and should be styled properly based on the `formstyle` argument.

Comment: Got it, Anthony. Thank you. Issue resolved after upgrading to web2py v.2.16.1. Was earlier on 2.14.6

Comment: Now I have another problem related to the autocomplete widget. I am not sure whether to post a new question or not. The issue is I cannot control the field width in the view using JQuery if field has autocomplete widget and default formstyle (bootstrap3_inline) is used. It can be controlled if other formstyles (tried table3cols &, table2cols) are used, but then I have to either  use a different formstyle only for that form or change the default formstyle in appconfig.ini. Is there no other way?

Comment: `jQuery('input#tablename_fieldname').css('width', '50%')` works for me. If not for you, start a new question and post your code.

Comment: Thanks again, Anthony!! It worked!! Mine was `jQuery('input[name=fieldname]').css('width', 200px)`. But I cannot understand the reason. The webpage source code  is identical in both cases. Even `name=tablename_fieldname` does not work.

Comment: With the autocomplete widget, the input with `name=fieldname` is hidden. The visible input has a special name, as well as `id=tablename_fieldname` (as used above). Note, you can use the inspect feature of the browser tools to see all of these attributes.

Comment: Oh.. Missed it. But @Anthony, I'm still not clear why under `formstyle` other than the default, width is displayed properly, even though the width is not explicitly given for the input tag. _page source snippet with formstyle’table3cols’ & jQuery('input[name=bank]').css('width','200px')_
`<input autocomplete="off" class="string" id="dd_master_bank" name="_autocomplete_bank_full_name_aux" onblur="jQuery('#_autocomplete_bank_full_name_div').delay(500).fadeOut('slow');" type="text">
<input id="_autocomplete_bank_full_name_auto" name="bank" type="hidden" value="" style="width: 200px;">`

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. The above code does add an explicit `width` style to the hidden input tag, but that has no effect on the display as that input is hidden. At least in Chrome, I don't see any difference in this behavior between the default formstyle and Bootstrap.